# Multi Language in SFDC in Chat Landing Page

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, sfdc

When Agents accepts a chat, they can reply to customers only in English. I want to activate some other languages for this communication

Comment: Ok, good luck with that.

Comment: This is not a good programming question.Try on salesforce.stackexchange.com with such admin stuff. From what I remember from LiveAgent configuration it's just that - config, not code. You define languages as new "Skills", only few agents have "German" skill, you deploy the new button (copy-paste generated HTML that includes skill id) on your German-speaking page and done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because general SF Admin questions have wider audience at salesforce.stackexchange.com and because author did zero research in the matter...